# Custom size (width, height) for anchor in TCPDF

Tags: php, html, anchor, tcpdf

I'm trying to create an anchor with a custom size (width, height). Basically I want to have menu-like link.

If I put the link as html inside a cell with custom dimensions, the anchor is not active on the entire cell, just on the text...

I have also tried addHtmlLink() but I "failed" again.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: try giving sufficient padding to anchor tag, so that it fills the cell. it works for html, don't know if it does for tcpdf.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but in tcpdf html padding does not work. To use padding you have to actually use an internal function (like $pdf->setCellPaddings();)